# Webscrape complex tables using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have tried almost everything I know to web scrape from the following link https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnplants.2016.167/MediaObjects/41477_2016_BFnplants2016167_MOESM277_ESM.pdf, Supplementary table 8, from page 26. I have not managed to do it with datapasta and rvest and the code below:

```
read.table(text="copy paste")
```

And I would like your input on how to web scrape complex tables from online.

Comment: thank you and my apologies for they typo

Comment: I think what you are looking for is PDF-scraping. Try e.g. `tabulizer::extract_areas(url, pages = 27:28)`. In RStudio this will open a shiny gadget which allows you to interactively select the area you want to extract from your pdf and returns the content as a list of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a possible solution using pdftools.
Note as_tibble is not necessary I only use it for pretty printing.

**COMMENT**: Looking at the pdf, Supplementary table 8 is at page 27 not 26, so i don't know if you want table 7 from page 26 or table 8 from page 27 (the code does the second). Nevertheless, edit the code at your convenience. Same is valid for the `matches` regexp: it matches the lines of the mentioned table.

```r
library(pdftools)
#> Using poppler version 22.04.0

url <- "https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnplants.2016.167/MediaObjects/41477_2016_BFnplants2016167_MOESM277_ESM.pdf"

lines <- pdf_text(url) |> strsplit("\n") |> unlist()   # suppresWarnings if you want

from <- grep("^Supplementary Table 8" , lines)
to   <- grep("^Supplementary Table 9" , lines)

headers <-  lines[seq(from, to)][grep(" +gene id" , lines[seq(from, to)])[1]]  |> 
  trimws() |> strsplit("  +") |> unlist()

matches <- regexec(
  "(\\S{9}) +(\\d+\\.\\d+|Inf) +(\\d+\\.\\d+|Inf) +(\\d+\\.\\d+|Inf) +(\\S+) +(.*)",
  lines[seq(from, to)] )

table <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, regmatches(lines[seq(from, to)], matches) |> sapply("[", -1)))
colnames(table) <- headers

print(tibble::as_tibble(table))
#> # A tibble: 43 × 6
#>    `gene id` A.thaliana C.hirsuta foldChange Name      Description              
#>    <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                    
#>  1 AT2G23340 336.63     770.89    2.29       DEAR3     ethylene-responsive tran…
#>  2 AT4G16610 41.56      151.80    3.65       AT4G16610 C2H2-like zinc finger pr…
#>  3 AT1G26260 62.80      162.01    2.58       CIB5      transcription factor bHL…
#>  4 AT5G04840 143.62     461.98    3.22       AT5G04840 bZIP protein             
#>  5 AT5G66350 42.91      131.64    3.07       SHI       Lateral root primordium-…
#>  6 AT5G65510 40.84      1166.91   28.57      AIL7      AINTEGUMENTA-like 7 prot…
#>  7 AT5G57390 191.57     756.34    3.95       AIL5      AP2-like ethylene-respon…
#>  8 AT5G56270 235.78     515.99    2.19       ATWRKY2   putative WRKY transcript…
#>  9 AT5G51990 0.00       5.45      Inf        CBF4      dehydration-responsive e…
#> 10 AT5G46880 651.22     1337.28   2.05       HB-7      homeobox-leucine zipper …
#> # … with 33 more rows
```

Comment: Dear Ric, 
Thank you so much for the help. 
Maybe I am wrong, I need Sup Table 8, and when I checked again, it spans from pages 26 - 27; look page number at the bottom. However, you are right. This is the actual page 27 when I exclude the cover. I think somehow we are both right